# serve video files with tornado web server and nginx

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, tornado

i need to serve large video files over the web and i set up a webserver handling upload and other stuff with tornado behind nginx.

what is the best way to serve those files? 
should i use tornado asynch to do this or is there a nginx module to do that?

i would also need offsets on those videos.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production, you probably want to serve static files from a more optimized static file server like nginx. You can configure most any web server to support these caching semantics. 
The nginx configuration FriendFeed use/used:

```
location /static/ {
    root /var/friendfeed/static;
    if ($query_string) {
        expires max;
    }
 }
```

Comment: yes i figured. i decided to use the ningx [h264 module](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Nginx-Version2) to serve my mp4 files because this module supports byte offsets. the other files will be served as static files.